# how to Disabled specify row data in Json?

Tags: json, extjs

How to disabled specify row ,my code already have function 'rowdblclick' and i want specify row to be unclickable or disabling.My "Id" field is specify by 1 and 0 so when my "ID" Field detect 0 then the row become read data only below is my json code:

```
plColModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([

{header: "Username", sortable: 'true', width: 85, dataIndex: 'UserName' },

{header:"Id",width:45,renderer:putRoleText,dataIndex:'Role',summaryRenderer:putTotalText,align:'center' },

{header: "Amount", width: 100, renderer: format2Dec, dataIndex: 'Amt', align: 'right', summaryType:'sum'}

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log `yourgrid.selModel.getSelected()` in your rowdblclick function and see how you can retrieve id from there.